# How to stop Gemfile.lock file from being changed again and again automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`Gemfile.lock` is appearing again and again in my project root folder even after `git checkout --` command several times. What can I do to get rid of this?

Running the `spring stop` command helps to stop the generation for a while. But after some time, it keeps on generating again.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

  Gemfile.lock
```

How would I get rid of this ?

Answer (score 1):

`Gemfile.lock` is for storing actual versions of gems that were used at last `bundle install`/`bundle update` (so that `bundle install` will install these exact versions later), it is very useful to ensure your app will not break if some dependency suddenly release a non-compatible version.

Normally this file is committed into the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Since, spring is used to speed up the development process. But we can stop this changes happening again and again by:

```
export DISABLE_SPRING=true
```

Then, comment out all the spring dependencies from the Gemfile. And restart the server.

Answer (score -2):

Gemfile.lock changes if you're adding new gems.

If you want to stop track it in git, add it in ./gitignore